# Bearings question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Kim leaves his house and walks for $2$ km on a bearing of $155^\circ$. How far south is Kim from his house now, to $1$ decimal place?

I don't know where to start at all, the correct answer is $1.8$km. The only thing I can do is draw a diagram, but I don't know what the question is asking me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Drawing a picture helps.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be the origin which is the location of her house, let $A$ be the point corresponds to the bearing of $155^\circ$. Then $A$ is in the IV quadrant and $OA = 2$. Let $B$ be the point on the vertical axis such that $OB \perp BA$. We solve for $OB$. We have: $OB = OA\cos 25^\circ = 2\cos 25^\circ = 1.81$ km

Answer (score 0):

Bearing is an angle measured from north clockwise, so east is $90^\circ$ and south is $180^\circ$. Bearing $155^\circ$ is 25 degrees less than south direction. Chose a starting point on a paper sheet and draw a line downwards - this is south bearing. Draw a line from starting point at angle $25^\circ$ from south to the right-hand side of a paper - this is Kim's route. Mark a distance of 2km (in a proper scale, of course). This is the endpoint of Kim's walk. So at the endpoint Kim is *some* distance south and *some* distance east from his house. You're asked to determine the southern component of his displacement.